# Short story, possibly titled "Walk to the New Moon", about a time-travelling Neanderthal girl

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

A Neanderthal girl is separated from her tribe in a field hunting cattle. She returns to her tribe at full moon or new moon traveling through time.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, did you read it in an anthology, a magazine, or online?

Answer (score 18):

This must be *[Walk to the Full Moon](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?101867)*, a short story by the Australian author Sean McCullen, first pblished in F&SF in December 2002.

The story concerns a girl with a sloping forehead and speaking an unknown language who is found in Spain, hunting a bull. A linguist learns to speak with the girl, Els, and it is discovered that she is a member of an unknown, ancient race of humans. Initially she was thought to be a Neanderthal, but DNA testing showed her to be closer to Homo Heidelbergensis. Using her language, they name her race the "Rhuun".

Eventually Els tires of being studied, and tries to escape, and calls to the linguist "Tek orr brii", meaning "Walk to the full moon". It turns out that the Rhuun have the ability to travel forwards in time, and so they can dodge ice ages, or famines, simply by stepping forward in time. The linguist ends up travelling with Els and her tribe to the far future, where they find safety after Homo Sapiens has eliminated itself.